# My JDBC connection is paramterized using Property file and I am reading value using ${__P(propertyname)}

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter My JDBC connection is paramterize using `Property file` and I am reading value `using ${__P(propertyname)}` but it is reading only first value and not reading second value from property file. 
Created a custom property file

> Server1=10:1433;Instance=SQL2014;DatabaseName=Repository15;domain=ABC
>   Server2=20:1433;Instance=SQL2008R2;DatabaseName=Repository14;domain=ABC

In Jmeter Test Plan i have two threads. Under each thread i have added JDBC Connection Configuration

```
First Thread Database URL = ${__P(Server1)}
Second Thread Database URL =  ${__P(Server2)}
```

when we run the test it is reading only first property file and ending the connection

Comment: Add your properties and your calls to question

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [different variable name](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) for each `JDBC Connection Configuration` and connect the relevant `JDBC Requests` for each.

> Each name must be different. If there are two configuration elements using the same name, only one will be saved. JMeter logs a message if a duplicate name is detected.